# Chrome extension Can't send data from background to content

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome

I try to copy some cookies(in text format) to the clipboard. In `content_script.js` it's not a problem, but when I try to copy something into the clipboard in the `background.js` it doesn't work because it's not supported. So I decided to send the text from background.js to content_script.js and from there on I can copy it to the clipboard.

I use `chrome.tabs.query()` and `chrome.tabs.sendMessage()` to achieve this. Everytime I run my extension I get the following error inside the background console: *Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.*

manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "Cookies to Desktop",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": [
        "content_script.js"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "host_permissions": [
    "*://*.google.com/*"
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "cookies",
    "contextMenus",
    "clipboardWrite",
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

background.js:

```
function foo() {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id,
            {
                message: "copyText",
                textToCopy: "some text"
            }, function (response) { })
    })
}

foo()
```

content_script.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function (textToCopy) {
        console.log('SUCCESS ' + textToCopy)
        alert('SUCCESS')
    }
)
```

How can I successfully send data from background to content

Comment: You have to do it in reverse